# Оба кандидата набирают равное число голосов

Tags: лексика, лексическая-сочетаемость

Оба кандидата набирают равное число голосов.
Оба участника финишировали одновременно.
Оба йогурта одинаково полезны.

Такое ощущение, что "оба" совершенно лишнее.
Настолько часто слышу подобное, что уже засомневался. 
Есть ли тут лексическая ошибка?

(+)
Это еще ничего.
Вот когда ***"оба" дали разные ответы***, адреналину бывает поболее.
Или ***"мы с братом оба разные"***.

Уточняю, на всякий случай. Меня не интересует, как можно еще сказать, мне стало интересно, зачем здесь нужно "оба"?
Могут ли два объекта быть равны или похожи, но не "оба"?

Comment: @Niemand, *То есть просто убрать*  - я этого не говорил. Но лично Вам не могу запретить изъясняться подобным образом.  *Нда, языковое чутье — это не шутка. Не хухры-мухры.* - и это не я сказал.

Comment: Как же тогда вас понимать? "Совершенно лишнее" обычно означает "можно выбросить", нет?

Comment: *Как же тогда вас понимать* - Так и понимайте. Что употребление "оба" тут совершенно излишне.  *"Совершенно лишнее" обычно означает "можно выбросить", нет?* - Если вам деньги лишние дали, их можно выбросить? Niemand, задавайте вопросы по сути, на эту фигню я не очень склонен отвечать.

Answer (score 2):

Могут ли два объекта быть равны или похожи, но не "оба"?

Оба/обе - заменяют **уже упомянутые** числительные два/две и придают им значение **собирательности**, например:

**Два лыжника** боролись за первое место, **оба** участника финишировали одновременно.
При голосовании в числе лидеров оказались **два йогурта**, затем эксперты  определили, что **оба** йогурта одинаково полезны.

**Неверно:** мы с братом оба разные, здесь отсутствует значение собирательности.

**Пояснение**

Слова оба и обе относятся к **собирательным** числительным. Кроме значения **совместности** (как и другие собирательные числительные), они имеют дополнительное значение **указания на уже упомянутые предметы и лица**.

Я был озлоблен, он угрюм, игру страстей мы знали оба.
Мы оба лжём, и оба это знаем.
Пред испанкой благородной двое рыцарей стоят, оба смело и свободно в очи прямо ей глядят.

По поводу слов оба, обе в науке нет единого мнения. Одни лингвисты считают их указательными местоимениями в значении **и тот и другой,** другие относят их к собирательным числительным на том основании, что они по значению близки числительному двое.

Comment: *оба участника финишировали одновременно* - т. е. вы тоже предполагаете возможность использования "оба", когда есть "равно"? Забавно...  тавтологичности совсем не видите? Остальное - интересно, конечно, но к моему вопросу особого отношения не имеет. А из классики есть что-нибудь подобное?

Comment: Оба одинаково обожали азартные игры (Л. М. Леонов). Паша и Лара оба кончили, оба одинаково блестяще, оба получили предложения в один и тот же город на Урале (Б. Л. Пастернак). На порогѣ оба одинаково держа руки за спиной, стояли м-сье Пьеръ и директоръ ― и тихо, деликатно, двигая только зрачками, осматривали общество (В. В. Набоков).

Answer (score 1):

> > Есть ли тут лексическая ошибка?

Ну, разумеется. Если неприкаянная мысль бродит бесцельно, не видя, к чему бы еще приложить свою глубину, то лексические ошибки можно обнаружить всюду. Да везде, если присмотреться, ошибки! Главное – посильнее напрячься.

Answer (score 0):

Если эти фразы имеют предваряющие вводные («За 3-е место шла борьба между А и Б. Оба участника финишировали одновременно» и «Сравним эти два продукта и поймём, что оба йогурта одинаково полезны»), то здесь *оба* приемлемо и даже необходимо. Не будь его, надо бы было замещать местоимением.

Третья фраза (адреналиновая) не вполне правомерна: (1) количественное местоимение *оба* не является полным синонимом счётному числительному *два*, (2) не оба разные, а выданные ими ответы. Помочь фразе выглядеть прилично может уточнение: *оба дали разные *неверные* ответы*.

Фраза «мы с братом оба разные» лексически неправильна: объединяющее *оба* тому причина. Здесь оно при наличии слова *мы* излишне. А вот тут всё в норме: «Хоть ни в чем не схожие [*хоть и разные*]— оба хороши».

Comment: *Если эти фразы имеют предваряющие вводные.* - а причем тут "вводные"? *«Сравним эти два продукта и поймём, что оба йогурта одинаково полезны»* - если их всего два, как они могут быть "одинаково полезны" не оба? И даже если не два, то почему оба?

Comment: *тоже вполне может быть правомерна, когда таковых двое* - вы подменили понятие "разные=неодинаковые" на "различные". Согласен, формально меня подловили, но вопрос-то не о том был.  Замените "дают" на "дали" - и желание такой подмены будет существенно меньшим.

Comment: 1. причем тут "вводные"? ==== Если они есть, то ОБА уместно. 2. если их всего два, как они... ===== Из нескольких выбирают два для сравнения. 3. то почему оба? ==== ОБА, что бы не повторяться, употребляя ДВА ещё раз.

Comment: *Если они есть, то ОБА уместно.* - обоснуйте, пожалуйста зачем.  *ОБА, что бы не повторяться, употребляя ДВА ещё раз.* - а зачем "два" повторять?  Ну скажите "они", если уж на язык чего-то просится, а повторяться не хочется.  Ладно, вы, похоже, уперлись, Спасибо.

Comment: Есть в Ответе: Не будь его, надо бы было замещать местоимением.

Comment: Ну уже лучше, хотя необходимости замещать не вижу. Внимание, вопрос. Зачем нужно "оба", "Сравнив  два йогурта, выяснили, что (эти) йогурты одинаково полезны"?

Comment: Тоже нормально, как и наименования каждого.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40143/discussion-between-behemothus-and-shampar).

Comment: Не сейчас. Спасибо.

Comment: Как скажете. )))